# Angularjs - Restangular call inside factory/service

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-service, restangular, angularjs-factory

I am using `factory` as follows:

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', ['ngRoute','restangular']);

appModule
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller:  'ngHomeControl'
      })
      .when('/contacts', {
        templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
        controller:  'ngContactControl'
      });
  }]);

appModule
  .factory('testFactory', function testFactory(Restangular) {
    return {
      getFriendList: function() {
        return Restangular
          .all('api/users/getfriendsinvitations/')
          .getList()
          .then(function(response) {
            //
          });
      } 
    }
  });

appModule
  .controller('ngHomeControl', function($scope, testFactory) {
    $scope.homeFriends = testFactory.getFriendList();
  });

appModule
  .controller('ngContactControl', function($scope, testFactory) {
    $scope.contactFriends = testFactory.getFriendList();
  });
```

Here I can't get the value for `$scope.homeFriends` & `$scope.contactFriends` from the `Restangular` call. Can anyone suggest to me how to get values from `Restangular` call using `factory`/`service`?

Comment: Since the method getFriendList returns a promise, you may need to bind to your list using the `then` callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found:

```
appModule
  .factory('testFactory', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    return {
      getFriendList: Restangular
        .all('api/users/getfriendsinvitations/')
        .getList();
    }
  }]);

testFactory.getFriendList.then(function(homeFriends) {
  $scope.homeFriends = homeFriends;
}
```