# Cant get restangular factory to work

Tags: angularjs, factory, restangular, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing here but I cant get this to work..
I want to use a factory so that I can reuse the data in multiple controllers.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('www')
    .factory('profileFactory', profileFactory);

profileFactory.$inject = ['Restangular'];

/* @ngInject */
function profileFactory(Restangular) {

    var service = {
        getUserData: Restangular.one('/user/profile/').getList(),
        getFriendList: Restangular.all('api/users/getfriendsinvitations/').getList()
    };
    return service;

    }
})();
```

The controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('www')
        .controller('ProfileController', ProfileController);

    ProfileController.$inject = ['profileFactory'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function ProfileController() {

      activate();

      function activate(profileFactory, $scope) {
       profileFactory.getFriendList.then(function (homeFriends) {
         $scope.homeFriends = homeFriends;
       });
      }
    }
})();
```

And I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFriendList' of undefined"

Edit: I have tried this as well, https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#decoupled-restangular-service, but no luck!

Comment: Please form an actual question in your title. It looks like tags. Also, please expand on the efforts you've made to solve this yourself. Did you check documentation of 1st/3rd party libraries?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker file? We need to know another details like: "the way you call the service", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You factory is not defined correctly. In order to make available factory function to the service consumer, You should define factory that code in function, Also return that promise will help you to continue promise chain.

**Code**

```
function profileFactory(Restangular) {

    var service = {
        getUserData: function(){
           return Restangular.one('/user/profile/').getList();
        },
        getFriendList: function(){
           return Restangular.all('api/users/getfriendsinvitations/').getList();
       }
    };
    return service;
}
```

**Controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('www')
        .controller('ProfileController', ProfileController);

    ProfileController.$inject = ['profileFactory', '$scope'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function ProfileController(profileFactory, $scope) { //<==added dependancy here

      activate();

      function activate() {
       profileFactory.getFriendList().then(function (homeFriends) {
         $scope.homeFriends = homeFriends;
       });
      }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Also I found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496041/angularjs-restangular-call-inside-factory-service, so it looks like it should work!(?)

Comment: No difference.. still same error but this also added a jshint error... I have "profileFactory" injected into the activate() function so that should not be the problem.

Comment: @Mackelito remove `profileFactory, $scope`' from `activate` function..do look at edit

Comment: Ah.. you are correct! :) now I'm getting "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" so that is another problem :)

Comment: @Mackelito look at update answer it was simply change to `profileFactory.getFriendList()` added function bracket

Comment: Yepp.. I already updated that as well but still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the profileFactory service inside the controller's function.